# Moq - Is it possible to specify in a Setup the Verify criteria (e.g. Times called)?

Tags: testing, mocking, installation, moq, verify

If you need to Setup a return value, as well as Verify how many times the expression was called, can you do this in one statement?

From what I can gather, Moq's `Setup(SomeExpression).Verifiable()` called along with `Verify()`, basically does a `Verify(SomeExpression, Times.AtLeastOnce)`? i.e. it verifys the expression was called only.

Here's an example to explain the question better. For an interface:

```
interface IFoo
{
    int ReturnSomething();
}
```

Are the following two blocks equivalent (other than the first will Verify all setups marked as verifiable)?

```
void Test()
{
    var mock = new Mock<IFoo>();
    mock.Setup((m) => m.ReturnSomething()).Returns(1).Verifiable();

    mock.Verify();
}
```

and

```
void Test()
{
    var mock = new Mock<IFoo>();
    mock.Setup((m) => m.ReturnSomething()).Returns(1);

    mock.Verify((m) => m.ReturnSomething(), Times.AtLeastOnce());
}
```

If I wanted to verify the number of calls (say twice), is this the only way, where the expression is repeated for the Setup and Verify?

```
void Test()
{
    var mock = new Mock<IFoo>();
    mock.Setup((m) => m.ReturnSomething()).Returns(1);

    mock.Verify((m) => m.ReturnSomething(), Times.Exactly(2));
}
```

I just don't like having to call Setup and Verify. Well, since this is a good idea for AAA, to rephrase, I don't like having to repeat the expression for the Setup and Verify. At the moment I store the expression in a variable and pass it to each method, but doesn't feel so clean.

PS - The context for this is for a test checking when a cache is updated or not (expirations etc.)

Comment: This is using Moq 4 (I have seen old code snippets where there are methods on the ISetup such as AtMostOnce)

Answer (score 29):

I have this problem all the time. I use strict mocks, and I want to specify strictly (i.e. I used `It.Is<>()` instead of `It.IsAny()`) as well as verify strictly (i.e. specifying Times). You cannot use verifiable for this sadly, because Moq is missing a `Verifiable(Times)` overload.

The full expression of the call, including `It.Is<>()` is generally big. So in order to avoid duplication I generally resort to the following:

```
Expression<Action<MockedType>> expression = mockedTypeInstance => mockedTypeInstance.MockedMethod(It.Is<TFirstArgument>(firstArgument => <some complex statement>)/*, ...*/);
_mock.Setup(expression);

/* run the test*/

_mock.Verify(expression, Times.Once);
```

Not extremely readable, but I don't think there is another way to both use strict setup and strict verification.

Comment: The use of a separate expression to be re-used fits nice on what I need. Nice solution!

Comment: great idea, but how to use it if i want the setup to Return a value?

Comment: @ishayle just do as you would normally, use the fluent syntax for moq e.g. _mock.Setup(expression).Returns(...)

Comment: do we still need to specify setup and verify (for asserting Times) in the newer versions of moq? or any change or different way of doing it?

Comment: If you want to use `Returns(...)`, you may have to specify an Expression type that uses Func instead of Action, e.g.: `Expression<Func<MockedType, SetupReturnedType>>`

Answer (score 17):

To answer the first question, yes the two blocks are equivalent. Both will fail when `.Verify` is called if the method on the mock wasn't called.

You can't specify the verify up front as far as I am aware and if you think about it, it makes sense.

This is specifying the behavior of the mock:

```
mock.Setup(m => m.ReturnSomething()).Returns(1);
```

This is verifying the behavior of the caller:

```
mock.Verify(m => m.ReturnSomething(), Times.AtLeastOnce());
```

Personally I prefer calling verify individually to confirm the required behavior of the caller, the `.Verifiable()` and `.Verify()` are shortcuts that are less strict (they just check the method was called one or more times) however if you know your code should only call a method once, put the verify in at the end to confirm it.

I started doing that after a code merge resulted in a method being called twice, the test still passed since it was called at least once but it also meant that something else happened multiple times which shouldn't have!

Comment: That is unfortunate, considering Rhino Mocks supports setup and verify in a single statement.  I'd think this would be one of the most common use-cases (if not _the_ most common), so I'm baffled how this is not included in the framework, even now, over three years later.  Guess I'll switch to Rhino Mocks...

Answer (score 9):

Expounding on the answer by Evren Kuzucuoglu, I created the following extension methods to make creating the expressions a little simpler:

```
/// <summary>
/// Creates a method call expression that can be passed to both <see cref="Setup"/> and <see cref="Verify"/>.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Mocked object type.</typeparam>
/// <param name="mock">Mock of <see cref="T"/>.</param>
/// <param name="expression">Method call expression to record.</param>
/// <returns>Method call expression.</returns>
public static Expression<Action<T>> CallTo<T>(this Mock<T> mock, Expression<Action<T>> expression) where T : class
{
    return expression;
}

/// <summary>
/// Creates a method call expression that can be passed to both <see cref="Setup"/> and <see cref="Verify"/>.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Mocked object type.</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="TResult">Method call return type.</typeparam>
/// <param name="mock">Mock of <see cref="T"/>.</param>
/// <param name="expression">Method call expression to record.</param>
/// <returns>Method call expression.</returns>
public static Expression<Func<T, TResult>> CallTo<T, TResult>(this Mock<T> mock, Expression<Func<T, TResult>> expression) where T : class
{
    return expression;
}
```

Usage example:

```
var createMapperCall = mockMappingFactory.CallTo(x => x.CreateMapper());
mockMappingFactory.Setup(createMapperCall).Returns(mockMapper.Object);

mockMappingFactory.Verify(createMapperCall, Times.Once());
```

Answer (score 3):

I created a utility class that takes care of this:

```
public class TestUtils
{
  private static List<Action> verifyActions = new List<Action>();

  public static void InitVerifyActions() => verifyActions = new List<Action>();

  public static void VerifyAllSetups()
  {
    foreach (var action in verifyActions)
    {
      action.Invoke();
    }
  }

  public static ISetup<T> SetupAndVerify<T>(Mock<T> mock, Expression<Action<T>> expression, Times times) where T : class
  {
    verifyActions.Add(() => mock.Verify(expression, times));
    return mock.Setup(expression);
  }

  public static ISetup<T, TResult> SetupAndVerify<T, TResult>(Mock<T> mock, Expression<Func<T, TResult>> expression, Times times) where T : class
  {
    verifyActions.Add(() => mock.Verify(expression, times));
    return mock.Setup(expression);
  }
}
```

Then in TestInitialize(), I call TestUtils.InitVerifyActions(), and in the unit tests:

```
TestUtils.SetupAndVerify(myMock, m => m.Foo("bar"), Times.Once()).Returns("baz");
TestUtils.SetupAndVerify(myOtherMock, m => m.Blah(), Times.Once());
...
TestUtils.VerifyAllSetups();
```

Answer (score 0):

While far from enough Moq indeed has the `AtMost()` and `AtMostOnce()` methods on the `Setup` call, however it is marked as `Obsolete`, but it appears to be a mistake according to this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/moq/moq4/issues/1210)